# Symfony: inject bundle param configuration from service method

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, twig, yaml

New to Symfony and trying to configure bundle, passing param via service method call, but facing error. 
Symfony Version: 2.8

```
 ServiceNotFoundException in
 CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 58: 
 The service "twig" has a dependency on a non-existent service
 "=service('app.service.myservice').gethellostring()".
```

Goal: Pass parameter to bundle from service method call

Example:

app/config/services.yml:

```
...
    app.service.myService:
        class: AppBundle\Service\MyService

    #for configuration of other service it works perfect, but not for bundle
    app.service.myOtherService:
        class: AppBundle\Service\MyOtherService 
        arguments: ['@=service('app.service.MyService').getHelloString()']


...
```

app/config/config.yml:

```
...
    twig:
        globals:
            helloString: "@=service('app.service.MyService').getHelloString()"

...
```

Comment: Is services.yml app/services.yml?  If not are your sure the services.yml file is being processed?  Comment the offending line from config.yml (to get past the error) then run bin/console debug:container and see if myService shows up.

Comment: Yeap! They are located in app/config/ folder (I probably had to notice it) And yes, they are processed. Moreover, when I'm configuring other service to use dependency injection parameter value it works fine. But not for bundle

Comment: I don't use expressions much.  I know they work for service definitions and routes but I'm not sure they work for regular config stuff. https://symfony.com/doc/current/expressions.html  You might need to just set the service then call the method from inside of twig.

Comment: I need also config other bundles, like set credentials  for oAuth bundle and so on. I need "Config service" that will provide config for application from third side. So it's not only about twig.